# sketch points given by condition on complezx number z

Tags: complex-analysis

the condition is

$|z+i| \le 3$ so its a circle with radius three centered at -i

treating $z=x+iy$

$-\sqrt{9} \le \sqrt{(x^2 )+(y+1)^2} \le \sqrt{9}$

squaring everything $-9 \le x^2 + (y+1)^2 \le 9$

$-9 \le x^2 + y^2 + 2y +1 \le 9$

I feel like I am complicating more than I need to.

Comment: square root of nonnegative number is a nonnegative number so on the left you only need 0 not $-\sqrt 9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close.

Well $|z+i|\le 3$ with $z=x+iy$ we have then simply $0\le\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}\le3$ ($\forall Z\in\mathbb{C},\,|Z|\ge 0$).

Thus $x^2+(y+1)^2\le3^2$ which represents the disk of radius $3$ and center $(0,-1)$.

Comment: continue to 
$-9-2y-1 \le x^2+y^2 \le 9 - 2y -1$ which seems to make it worse too. I get it but inequalities have never been a strong suit for me. $-3 \le \sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2} \le 3$ how would I continue to solving the inequality?

Comment: Always try to have more exact inequalities, which means when you have $a\le X\le b$ try to have $b-a$ as small as possible. When you have only one side then try to have it as close as possible to $X$. $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,x^2\ge-10$ but a more exact version is $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,x^2\ge0$. Precision is good. Anyway you don't need to have $-3\le\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}\le3$ whereas you know that $0\le\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}$. David said it to. Even if you want to follow up with $-3\le\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}\le3$ then you'll get $0\le x^2+(y+1)^2\le9$ and in the second comment I'll explain why:

Comment: Suppose that $a<X<b$ where $a\ge 0$ (so of course $b>0$). Since the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}^+$ then $a^2<X^2<b^2$. Now suppose $b\le 0$ (so of course $a<0$). Since the function $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly decreasing then the order changes: $b^2<X^2<a^2$ or if you want you can do $-b<-X<-a$ where $-b\ge 0$ and use what's previous to get $b^2<x^2<a^2$.
But what if $a<0$ and $b>0$ and $a<X<b$? We know that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,x^2\ge0$ so of course $0\le X^2$. Then what is $c$ such as $0\le X^2<c^2$? In the third comment I'll explain why:

Comment: A such $X$ can be either positive, negative or $0$. If it's 0 we're done: $X^2=0$. If it's negative then $a<X<0$. Applying what's in the second comment lends to $0<X^2<a^2$. If it's positive then $0<X<b$ and so $0<X^2<b^2$. So, is $c=a$ or $c=b$? (Don't forget we want precision so $c=10^{10000}$ whereas $a=-1$ and $b=2$ isn't amusing^^). Then you'll say: we want precision so if $a^2<b^2$ then let's take $c=a$ because it's closer to $X$.But here, by choosing $a$, you're considering all the values of $X$ such as $-a<X<b$ doesn't exist. In fact who knows, maybe $X=\dfrac{b-a}{2}$.So:(4th comment)

Comment: We must choose $c$ from $a$ and $b$ so that we don't neglect any possible value of $X$. If we take for $c^2$ the smallest from $a^2$ and $b^2$, as explained in comment 3 we will neglect some values. But if we take the largest, what will we neglect? Nothing. So $c^2=max(a^2,b^2)$. Here I gave you general rule so that you can understand. I hope you did^^

Comment: I sorta get it, I think a few read throughs and I'll have it. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

1. Your first inequality is false. A positive number cannot be between negative numbers.
2. The second inequality does not follow from the first, squaring a negative is a positive.

You have

$$0\le \sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}\le 3$$

$$0\le x^2+(y+1)^2\le 9$$

This isn't necessary to sketch, but either way you know its a closed **disk** centered at $(0,-1)$ of radius $3$. You can get to here right from $|z+i|\le 3$.

Comment: 22 seconds of difference ^^. But the center is $(0,-1)$

Comment: oh whoops its not supposed to be a negative on either side.

Comment: so the points I sketch are $(3,-i), (-3,-i)$?

Comment: No, the entire disk